# SQL adding a number of months onto a date

Tags: date, dateadd

I have the below SQL code which I am wanting to take the number from the PPD.Month_Diff and add that number (of months) onto a column that is already in date format:

CONVERT(varchar, (DATEADD(MONTH,ED.books_close_date, PPD.Month_Diff)))

However when I run this code I get an error as below

Msg 8116, Level 16, State 1, Line 53
Argument data type datetime is invalid for argument 2 of dateadd function.

I'm not sure if its the conversion part or something else that I'm missing?

Answer (score 0):

Use the correct order of the parameters:

```
DATEADD(MONTH, PPD.Month_Diff, ED.books_close_date)
```

[DATEADD (Transact-SQL)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/dateadd-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16?WT.mc_id=M365-MVP-5002361)

Comment: Thanks for the help Gustav but unfortunately swapping the parameters around and using with or without the CONVERT(varchar, still encounters the same error?

Comment: Then some of your data are not acceptable for the function. It is not Convert. `CONVERT(varchar, SomeTrueDateTimeValue)` will always return a string.